# R as.data.frame multi-core

Tags: r

I'm downloading data from Statistics Lithuania using `rsdmx` package. But my problem is, that the transformation process `as.data.frame` takes sometimes very long. Are there any simple solutions to use multiple cores for this task, as the `as.data.frame` uses only one core thread. In my case ~5 minutes

```
library(rsdmx)
library(tidyverse)

new_config <- httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE)
httr::set_config(new_config, override = FALSE)

earn <- readSDMX(providerId = "LSD", resource = "data", flowRef = "S3R0050_M3060315_1", dsd = TRUE)%>%
  as.data.frame(.,labels = TRUE)
```

I tried:

```
numCores <- detectCores()
registerDoMC(cores = numCores)
```

But this does not help. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe what you are asking is possible. The object returned by the read function is a very complex one and `as.data.frame` is not a parallelized function. You would have to write your own parallelized function, if at all possible.

Comment: Using `{data.table}` I haven't noticed any appreciable performance gain. I am afraid you'll be forced to reduce object complexity.